# c++ Inheritance class constructor

Tags: c++, class, derived

I have a slight problem where to be honest I am totally confused with derived class constructors and need some help.

I have a base class with the parameterised constructor:

```
Element::Element(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console) 
: rnd(rnd), console(console)
```

and the derived class constructor of

```
Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber rnd, Console console):Element(rnd,console)
```

Basically I want to pass the parameters that are used within the base class constructor into the derived class constructor. I have tried a number of different ways and at the moment I am getting the error message 'no initializer for'.

Does anyone have any help for me or could assist me in understanding my problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Alyn.

edit :

```
IntelliSense: "Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber rnd, Console console)" provides no         initializer for:  e:\c++\my game\my game\jetsam.cpp   7
```

edit:

```
Element::Element(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console) 
: rnd(rnd), console(console)
{

}

Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber rnd, Console console):Element(rnd,console)
{

}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error? You've given only 3 words from the error.

Comment: Are your member variables declared as references? If so, your derived ctor also needs the same signature as the base.

Comment: What are types of base class' members `rnd` and `console` ?

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes they are declared as references, so how would I use the same sigs?

Comment: @borisbn they are type of class RandomNumber and Console

Comment: Can you post a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: What is true: "Yes they are declared as references" or "they are type of class RandomNumber and Console" ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal class definition of both classes and their member variables, i.e. provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Posting the same code twice does not help.

Answer (score 0):

`Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber rnd, Console console): Element::Element(rnd,console);`

The above code sample should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ref my comment - if your member variables are declared as references, you will need to define your derived constructor like this:

```
Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console):Element(rnd,console)
```

For example, the following code compiles ok for me:

```
// dummy classes for use as member variables
class RandomNumber{};
class Console{};

// base class
class Element
{
public:
    Element(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console) : rnd(rnd), console(console) {}

    // member variables
    RandomNumber& rnd;
    Console& console;
};

// derived class
class Jetsam : public Element
{
public:
    Jetsam(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console) : Element(rnd, console) {}
};
```

I've assumed that your declaration is similar to the above. Can you edit your question if it's significantly different?

Comment: This is what I initially used and still had the say error as above

Comment: Is there anything else you would like to see, my derived class constructors contains nothing within its body at the moment

Comment: Can you show a cut-down copy of your two classes that is similar in size to my code example above and that doesn't compile?

Comment: I've edited it slightly, but I unsure as to what else you would like.

Comment: If you chang `Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber rnd, Console console):Element(rnd,console)` to `Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console):Element(rnd,console)` it matches my example, which is ok. What error do you get if you do that?

Comment: I've done that and get the exact same error as mentioned in the first edit that I mentioned, the solutions that I have been given have not solved this error.